# Building JavaScript dropdowns based on nested json

Tags: jquery, underscore.js, jquery-templates, mustache, client-side-templating

Iam trying to build a html from a json object . My json will be in the following structure .

```
[{"Property1":[{"IsDropDown":"true","Value":"Drp1Value1"},
    {"IsDropDown":"true","Value":"Drp1Value2"},
    {"IsDropDown":"false","Href":"Link1"}]}, 
{"Property2":[{"IsDropDown":"true","Value":"Drp2Value1"},
    {"IsDropDown":"true","Value":"Drp2Value2"},
    {"IsDropDown":"false","Href":"Link1"}]}]**
```

From this json I need to build 2 dropdowns by checking the property IsDropDown and 1 anchor link (IsDropDown == false) . Please keep in mind that propery object (Property1) is not fixed in length and even the nested object in Property is also not fixed . So i need one or more templates from which i can solve this.

From the above json output should be like 2 dropdowns first dropdown consisting of values Drp1Value1, DrpValue2 and second dropDown consisting of values Drp2Value1 and DrpValue2 . and if IsDropDown is false then build a anchor tag with href from the json object (No repetation should be allowed in From the above json 2 dropdown of 2 values each and a anchor tag sho.lud be built)

There is no way i can change the json structure because it is from a third party api .  Is it possible with any of template frame works? i tried jTemplate and mustache.js but i was not able to do it .

Comment: If you show us what you've already done, you have a better chance of getting help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this working sample in [JQFaq.com](http://jsfiddle.net/L5XY2/1/). It has two dropdown boxes and when the first dropdown value changed it's childrens are displayed in second dropdown based on json data.

**CODE:**

```
var jsonData = [{
  "Property1": [{
    "IsDropDown": "true",
    "Value": "Drp1Value1"
  }, {
    "IsDropDown": "true",
    "Value": "Drp1Value2"
  }, {
    "IsDropDown": "false",
    "Href": "Link1"
  }],
  "Value": "Property1"
}, {
  "Property2": [{
    "IsDropDown": "true",
    "Value": "Drp2Value1"
  }, {
    "IsDropDown": "true",
    "Value": "Drp2Value2"
  }, {
    "IsDropDown": "false",
    "Href": "Link1"
  }],
  "Value": "Property2"
}];

var collection1 = [];
$.each(jsonData, function (key, value) {
  collection1.push(value.Value);
});

var $newOption = $.tmpl("<option>${Value}</option>", jsonData);
var $select = $("#Select1").append($newOption).change(function () {
  selectionChanged(this);
});
selectionChanged($select[0]);

function selectionChanged(select) {
  var selectedIndex = $.inArray(select.value, collection1);
  var newOpt = $.tmpl("<option>${Value}</option>", jsonData[selectedIndex][select.value]);
  $("#Select2").empty().append(newOpt);
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Accept as answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This block is probably what you're struggling with:

```
var i, j, p;
var out = '';
for (i=0; i < json.length; i++) {
  for (p in json[i]) {
    if (json[i].hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      out += 'select name='+p+'<br/>';
      for (j=0; j < json[i][p].length; j++) {
        if (json[i][p][j].IsDropDown == 'true') {
          out += ' option='+json[i][p][j].Value+'</br>';
        }
      }
      break; // from for loop, since we only want one select per top-level object
    }
  }
}
```

So I'm iterating the arrays with a regular `for` loop. But then I'm finding the name of the "Property" with a `for in` and `hasOwnProperty`.

Note that I didn't implement any of the other business logic, because I doubt you'll have problems there.

You can find a fiddle with this code and your data here: http://jsfiddle.net/5kKD9/